# Is it possible to show the method invoke time in rust production code?

Tags: rust, profiling

I have a rust function that is running in production. Is it possible to profile the production rust code and show each method's invoke time?

What should I do to know which method is slow? Like [arthas](https://github.com/alibaba/arthas) shows the method invoke hierarchy and how much time each method takes.

Comment: Something like arthas works because Java is running on a virtual machine. For code that compiles to machine code directly like Rust either the function (or it's caller) in question has to do the runtime measurement or you have to run it with a profiler.

Comment: I would first take a look at the Profiling category on lib.rs: https://lib.rs/development-tools/profiling.